# Charging LiFePO₄ battery using TP4056

Tags: esp32, lifepo4, tp4056

I'm working on a project that involves using a LiFePO₄ battery to power an ESP32 microcontroller without regulator to save energy.

I have a TP4056 Li-ion battery charger, which has a voltage of 4.2 V. I know that the charge voltage for LiFePO₄ batteries is 3.6 V, so I'm wondering if it's possible to use the TP4056 to charge the LiFePO₄ battery by adding a diode in series with a voltage drop of 0.6 V.

I also need to be able to charge the battery while it's supplying power to the ESP32. Can this be done safely, and if so, what do I need to keep in mind?

I should mention that I'm in Argentina, and it's difficult and/or expensive to obtain specific components like the CN3058E. So, I need a simple and cost-effective solution that can be implemented with what I have available, like the TP4056. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably not - the diode voltage drop goes to 0 as the current goes to 0.

Comment: If you have to hack it, one idea is to create a circuit that will divert the current away from the battery if the voltage is too high. Or one that turns off the charger if the voltage is too high. But, at that point you might be better off designing what kind of charging behaviour you need and then implementing that without the TP4056.

Comment: @user253751 If i use a diode with 0.65 V drop, I get a voltage Charge of 3.55 V, and I can put a 3.6 V zener in parallel with a resistor and a Led to divert current away from the battery and indicate that battery si Charged.

Comment: yeah something like that. Note that both normal diodes and low-voltage Zeners have voltage that changes according to the current. It's just an idea - I don't have a ready-made circuit for you.